# Spring Boot - JPA Hibernate not creating tables automatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on diploma project and faced problem that JPA not generating tables during application start. There is no errors in the console.

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/full_data
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DiplomaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiplomaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                .url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/full_data")
                .username("postgres")
                .password("password")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Base entity:

```
package com.diploma.diploma.impl.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public class BaseObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    protected String name;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BaseObject{"
                + "id=" + id
                + ", name='" + name
                + '\''
                + '}';
    }
}
```

Project entity:

```
package com.diploma.diploma.impl.model.project;

import com.diploma.diploma.impl.model.BaseObject;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
public class Project extends BaseObject {

    private String description;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Project{"
                + "id=" + id
                + ", name='" + name + '\''
                + ", description='" + description + '\''
                + '}';
    }

    public String[] toArray() {
        return new String[]{getId().toString(),
                getName(),
                getDescription()
        };
    }
}
```

I'm using Base entity because planning to create more entity objects, for now need to start app.
I've already tried different properties changes like set ddl-auto=update and others abut any change helped me.

Comment: Show the entities (including imports, and clarify which Spring BOot version you are using). The fact thatyou have all those annotations on your application is imho a clear indication you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Where are you actually using the Persistence unit and making JPA calls? Show the errors it gets when connecting to the DB and the tables aren't there as my guess isn't you don't have anything loading a persistence context; it is the context that creates the tables when it gets initialized.

Comment: There is no SQL errors during application start. It's successfully connecting to DB but when i'm calling repository it throws next error: 'org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "projects" does not exist', i already checked what is this error.

Comment: It looks like application not using .properties file, coz i've tried to commit datasource bean from main class and not it cannot connect to DB but properties available in the file.